# Where is the SharePoint Server Search Administration page? (how to reach it)

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007

I need to find this page to modify something in the settings, but I can\t reach it! SP 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Central Administration > SharedServices1 > Search > Search administration

The direct URL would be:

http://myserver:8888/ssp/admin/searchadministration.aspx

where myserver:8888 is the Shared Services server and port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SharePoint 2016, just for your reference. I get it by following steps:
1. Go to your Central Administration page
2. click "General Application Settings" link on left navigation panel
3. click link "Farm Search Administration" in Search section in page General Application Settings
4. click link "Search Service Application" in page Farm Search Administration

Then, I'm navigated to page "Search Administration".
My direct URL is
http://win-sharepoint:9000/searchadministration.aspx?appid=5bc8ec52-f4b1-4f1c-ae08-4fe9cc0ba6f6